# i need to update id for different run_date based on table

Tags: oracle, partition

i have demo  table like below i need update id based on table , time .

[image]

ent name and  bc code id should be updated based on ent name and ac code of nearest time and similarley for review name also.

desired output should as below,  Please help us i am new to this requirement.

[image]

```
UPDATE demo SET ID=select id, max(time) over (PARTITION  BY time order by time ASC)
time1,id,name,time from demo where trunc(time)= '28-MAR-23'
```

i got missing expression error.

Comment: that is not a valid SQL statement.  How do you expect to set ID to two values.  Look at using a WITH clause.

Comment: Could you provide more information i will try to get an idea.

Comment: Shouldn't the 4th row (first row with null id) be updated to 983 instead of 774?